# Extracting Rows from an Array in Python When One Element is Less than a Value in Python

Tags: python

I have an array of the following values in python:

```
 [['19480229' '-17' '-1.7']
 ['19520229' '6' '0.6']
 ['19560229' '-156' '15.6']
 ['19600229' '-78' '-7.8']
 ['19640229' '-128' '12.8']
 ['19680229' '-50' '-5']
 ['19720229' '228' '22.8']
 ['19760229' '78' '7.8']]
```

I am trying to perform the following operation: If any value in the middle column is less than or equal to -83, then it prints out the corresponding values in the left-hand column. In this example, it should print out '19560229', and '19640229'. So far I have the following code:

```
for i in array[:,1]:
    if i < -83:
        print (array[:,0])
```

This is the output:

```
[ 19480229.  19520229.  19560229.  19600229.  19640229.  19680229.19720229.  19760229.  19800229.  19840229.  19880229.  19920229. 19960229.  20000229.  20040229.  20080229.  20120229.]
```

It just prints all of the first column and not just 19560229 and 19640229. How might I properly re-edit this code to obtain the desired results?

Comment: show what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some commas in the array. I think you're meant to have this:

```
array =  [['19480229', '-17', '-1.7'],
 ['19520229', '6', '0.6'],
 ['19560229', '-156', '15.6'],
 ['19600229', '-78', '-7.8'],
 ['19640229', '-128', '12.8'],
 ['19680229', '-50', '-5'],
 ['19720229', '228', '22.8'],
 ['19760229', '78', '7.8']]
```

Now with that you can do the following:

```
for item in array:
    if int(item[1]) < -83:
        print(item[0])
```

This outputs 19560229 and 19640229.

You may want to store the numbers inside of the array as integers, so that you don't have to use `str()`, but that depends on what you're using it for.